# How to download a pdf from an embedded pdf viewer?

Tags: pdf, download

I was trying to download a pdf of a book and i tried doing everything i could within the inspect element, i found the xhr file within the network tab but it opens a page containing weird symbols. The i made the download and print option visible but the buttons do nothing.
https://onlinereso.in/api/getEbook?note_id=9420 ->This is the one found in network tab.
The main website: https://onlinereso.in/note/9420 but account is required. Please help in downloading the embedded pdf

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user apparently tries to download restricted files through bypassing a required login.

Comment: i have the login credentials, i just want to download for offline usage

Comment: well you got an answer anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

I right clicked the link YOU provided (https://onlinereso.in/api/getEbook?note_id=9420) and chose "Save Link As..." in firefox.  Change the getEBook.htm to IHateMath.pdf and you should be fine.

I now have a copy of this PDF... "MATHEMATICS (KVPY)".. now what the heck do I do with it??

Comment: No sir.  Sorry.  Telling you how to do it is one thing.  Helping you obtain copyrighted material is something completely different.  My instructions still work for me.  Simply follow my explanation above or if you are indeed legit, try emailing dlpd@resonance.ac.in for a copy.